# yellow paper: identifier for the final state

Tags: yellow-paper

I've started to read the yellow paper and in section 2 it's written: 
*Blocks function as a journal, recording a series of transactions together with the previous block and an identifier for the final state (though do not store the final state itself that would be far too big).*

What do they mean by identifier for the final state ? Where can we see it ? Is it appended to a variable ?

Answer (score 2):

Each block contains a `stateRoot` which is the root of the state of Ethereum World at that block.

This field is 32 bytes. The world state was not meant to be easily browsable by a person. It is designed for use by Ethereum clients to verify new blocks and transactions.